# PC tower shuts down during FreeDos installation

Tags: installation, freedos, compaq-desktop-computer

I have an old Compaq Presario PC tower (`i386`), and I'm trying to install ***FreeDos legacy*** on it. I created a partition for the `C:` drive, marked it active, rebooted and started installing the packages. About 25% of the way through, the tower shuts down, and the power button won't turn it back on. It works when I unplug it and plug it back, then turn it on, but I have to restart the installation. Does anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: I doubt a hardware issue. Can you keep it on with just the fdisk screen or any boot screen initially and wait for some time - time equivalent to the 25% completion of your freedos install. Someone had presented me a problem in the past that when they plug their laptop , it shows as "being charged" for first 5 minutes and then it goes to battery. The root cause was a loose wall socket's plug point!!! It somehow  took ~5 minutes for the plug to get "disconnected" from electric circuitry. Something similar must be happening to internal circuitry ( I doubt smps and capacitors)

Comment: I'll try and let it hang on the first screen of the installation cd for a bit.

Comment: @Sreejith.D.Menon I've let it sit on every screen for about half an hour, no problem on any of the other ones. I'm starting the installation again.

Comment: Did that work? If you are still facing issue... try running one of those live cd memory check program or run in-built memory diagnostics...please share with us - how that goes..

Comment: It hasn't worked so far, but I'll try and send you the results of the check.